# Function with output that initially increases input, but levels off and never surpasses a given value?

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function

I'm trying to find a function *f(x)* that will fit the following general pattern. Please note these aren't exact results but very rough approximations:

*f(0) = 0*; 
*f(5) = 29*; 
*f(25) = 59*; 
*f(50) = 68*; 
*f(100) = 69*;

So the output should be much higher than *x* while *x* is small, but it should level off after a while, never surpassing 70. I tried logarithms, but all the outputs I got were smaller than *x*. And adding a multiplier makes it grow past 70.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A variant of $y=-\frac 1x$ should get you pretty close

Comment: Cheating a little: $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{x}\dfrac{70}{k(k+1)}$. As $x\to\infty$, the sum is just $70$.

Comment: So using the approach of $f(\infty)=70$ we have $f(x)=g(x)+70$, and if we start with $g(x)=\frac ax$, then we can get $a\in[-250,-100]$, and depending on the need for accuracy we can just pick a value for $a$.  But then we have $f(0)=0$ which is not very easy to work with...